# How to check if Authenticated Origin Pulls is enabled?

Tags: security, ssl, iis, certificate

Lately, I was trying to activate Authenticated Origin Pulls (AOP) by authenticating through a certificate validation process. My site runs on a CDN (Content Distribution Network). I installed a certificate on the server and I activated AOP for the domain via a feature on the CDN network.

Is there a way to test if the end-to-end communication is authenticating origin pulls?

Comment: you could try to use the [network monitor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=4865) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html) and monitor tls session. when you use standard TLS session the flow look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xz8Tt.png) and with AOP the flow will look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH1Eb.png). you could refer this link for more detail [link1](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/204899617),[link2](https://serverfault.com/questions/764804/authenticated-origin-pulls-with-cloudflare-and-iis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I found in CF community, you can try to turn AOP off in the CF setting. If the server is configured properly, you should get an SSL certificate error. Turn AOP back on in Cloudflare and everything should work again. Try this in incognito mode to avoid Caching.